# SeriesCollection().Values sume all series

Tags: vba

I´m having trouble with my code because when the second serie is ploted it has the value of the sume of both series 1 and 2.
This is my code:

```
Dim Chart2 As ChartObject
Set Chart2 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=1380, Top:=450, Height:=380)
Chart2.Chart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Hours"
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("B93:S93)
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("B95:W95)
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "CdT"
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("B93:S93)
Chart2.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("B99:W99)
```

Thank you in advance¡

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but do you reset all values/set them to defautl values (e.g. `0`) before using again/looping?

Comment: Hi David, I don´t reset the values, how can I reset the values?